# Error:Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (response) } to equal { Object (response) }

Tags: json, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am facing an issue in test case when i am trying to do `deepEqual` where i am trying to compare the exact structure of result data with sample data.

the above is my sample json data which i created with the result of the actual data.

Code:

```
it('comparing structures',()=>{
        var result = instance.parseResponse(input,esResponse);
        console.log(result);
        assert.deepEqual( result, expectedJSON);
    });
```

Here in console i am getting the result .

[image]

Taking the result i am creating the sample data .

Code :

```
    var expectedJSON={
    "response":{
    "aggregate":{
        "average":43.833333333333336,
        "count":6,
        "max":90,
        "min":10,
        "total":263
    },
    "endDate":"Tue Jul 05 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "groupBy":"datetime",
    "metricType":"distance_metric",
    "quarters":[{
        "aggregate":{
            "average":0,
            "count":undefined,
            "max":0,
            "min":0,
            "total":0
        },
        "quarter":4,
        "startDate":"Invalid Date"
    }],
    "startDate":"Tue Jan 12 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "type":"person"
}
};
```

I am doing this because i need to create the exact Json structure and let anything may be the result the structure should match .

but i am getting the fail test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deepEqual have a lot of issues and is old now. Lot of new ECMA features aren't supported either. I found this one very interesting: https://github.com/zubuzon/kewlr

Answer (score 0):

When you use deepEqual it checks not only the structure of the object but also the type of object. In this case it is given by `__proto__`

Comment: yes in my actual structure it is response is DateMatric and in my expected structure it is just an object so do that matters?